# Выполнить функцию php через ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

я создал форму через которую можно создавать новые страницы для сайта. Нужно вызвать функцию через сервер и я использую ajax. Проблема в том что этот код не выполняется, я даже не знаю где может быть ошибка. Вот форма

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
    Name <input type="text" name="nameof" id="name" value="yourname"> 
    Text <input type="text" name="dataof" id="text" value="<b>your text</b> hello <i> example </i>">
    <button onclick="create()" name="select">post</button>

</form>

<script>

    function create () {
        $.ajax({
            url:"function.php",    
            type: "post",  
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {name: "nameof", data:"dataof"}
        });
    }


</script>
```

Файл function.php

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $data= $_POST['data'];
  $fp = fopen($name.'.html', "w+");
  fwrite($fp, $data);
  fclose($fp); ?>
```

Прошу помочь, буду благодарен

Comment: Уверен, что `POST()`, а не `POST[]`?

Comment: @u_mulder извиняюсь, я просто код переписывал после некоторых изменений и допустил грубнйшую ошибку :(

Comment: Но даже с исправлениями код не работает, возможно я не понимаю основ этого языка

Comment: Я не знаю, что здесь конкретно не работает: ajax-запрос или в самом php-файле ошибка. Поэтому постарайся описать __что именно__ не работает.

Comment: PHP файл без ошибок, я это проверял.  Все ещё работаю над кодом.

Comment: Была ошибка serealize () is not a function, возможно надо было ...val().serealize(), спасибо за помощь с кодом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте исправить ваш `HTML` код следуюшим образом предпологая что файл находиться в корне проекта:

```
<form id="myForm" name="form" action="/" method="post">
    Name <input type="text" name="nameof" id="name" value="yourname"> 
    Text <input type="text" name="dataof" id="text" value="<b>your text</b> hello <i> example </i>">
    <button onclick="create()" name="select">post</button>

</form>

<script>
function create () {
        $.ajax({
            url:"function.php",    
            type: "post",
            data: $('#myForm').serialize()
        });
    }
</script>
```

Метод .serialize () создает текстовую строку в стандартной записи с кодировкой URL.

**Update:**
Или следующим образом:

```
<form id="myForm" name="form" action="/" method="post">
        Name <input type="text" name="nameof" id="name" value="yourname"> 
        Text <input type="text" name="dataof" id="text" value="<b>your text</b> hello <i> example </i>">
        <button onclick="create()" name="select">post</button>
    
    </form>
    
    <script>
    function create () {
            $.ajax({
                url:"function.php",    
                type: "post",
                data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Файл function.php

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$flag = "done";
$fp = fopen($name.'.html', "w+");
if($fp && $name && $data){
    fwrite($fp, $data);
} else {
    $flag = "fail";
}  
fclose($fp); 

return $flag;
?>
```

При выполнении и записи вы получите в консоли вашего браузера ответ "done", и напротив "fail", если у вас что то пошло не так в файле php.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, сегодня наконец я разобрался как завести данный код. Я просто убрал форму, оставит только два label. И исправил `date: $('#myForm').serealize()` на `date: {name:$('#name').val(), text:$('#text').val()`, досихпор не знаю почему .serealize() не работал.